# FIRDataBaseReference not being recognized

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is a quick one I guess

I'm trying to use a Firebase database in my app and I'm doing the installation as the tutorials say. In my AppDelegate, I have already put the required code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}
```

In the viewcontroller I'm going to use the database, I have tried to declare a FIRDatabaseReference

```
var ref:FIRDatabaseReference!
```

But then I receive this message:

```
Use of undeclared type 'FIRDatabasereference'
```

What can I do? I have already imported Firebase in this specific viewcontroller too

Answer (score 2):

Just found out: needed to `import FirebaseDatabase` instead of `import Firebase` in this viewController

Answer (score 1):

```
import Firebase
var ref:FIRDatabaseReference = Database.database().reference() //this will give you a ref for database 

func viewDidLoad(){
        ref//you can directly use the reference over here
    }
```

or you can use

```
import Firebase
var ref:FIRDatabaseReference?

func viewDidLoad(){
    ref = Database.database().reference() //or any other refrence of child you want to use
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Firebase** is a  parent library, **FirebaseDatabase** is its child Library. So if you import *Firebase* , you don't have to import *FirebaseDatabase*, Thats why Xcode AutoComplete shows a red line on the Libraries that aren't necessary to include. *This isn't the issue.*

The problem is that you are trying to access the ***FIRDatabaseReference***, type present in Firebase Library during the very initial load of the app i.e at first every class in your app is executed to assign some *global* or *init* functions/variables associated with that class. There is a possibility that when your **ViewController**'s :

```
var ref:FIRDatabaseReference!
```

is trying to access **FIRDatabaseReference** , that type. i.e Firebase Library hasn't yet been compiled by the compiler so as of that instant the **FIRDatabaseReference** is a type that still doesn't exist.

***SOLUTION*** :

```
var ref:FIRDatabaseReference? = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("message")
```

my Pod File -- make sure to us Database you had installed pod for Firebase database

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. the code given below has solved my issue.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var ref : DatabaseReference?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = Database.database().reference()
    }

}
```